# Double pointer to structure

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use a double pointer to a structure. The build is successful, but on running, it gives the following error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'test2' is being used without being initialized.

The code is:

```
testStructure* test1 = (testStructure*)malloc(sizeof(testStructure));
testStructure** test2 ;
test1->Integer = 1;
test1->Double = 4.566;
*test2 = test1;
```

and the structure is:

```
typedef struct{
  int Integer;
  double Double;
} testStructure;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer test1 is a pointer to a structure in the memory. If you need another pointer to the same structure just `testStructure *test2 = test1` is sufficient. If you want to modify the address stored in test1 indirectly, then use `testStructure **test2 = &test1` so that test2 will be a pointer to the pointer that points to the structure. In your code `*test2 = test1` tries to access an arbitrary address (initial value of test2) and to set its value to the address of the structure.

Answer (score 13):

```
*test2 = test1;   // test2 is pointing no where to get dereferenced.
```

must be

```
test2 = &test1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `test2 = &test1` - i.e. test2 is the address of the pointer to test1